# Compare javascript strings ignoring special character "ä"

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

Problem is following: I want to compare two javascript strings that contain special character 'ä' in it. One of the strings comes from an environment variable. The other string I get from a third party. On my localhost (Windows), the comparison works as expected, but on the production environment server (ubuntu) the comparison doesn't work.

On the production environment, when I compare two strings that should be equal, containing 'ä' character, the result is that they are not equal. I suspect it is because of the 'ä' character.

What I would want is a comparison function that doesn't care about the special characters. A comparison function that should work no matter if it contains 'ä' characters. I wish I used docker, so I could avoid these kind of server surprises.

Comment: Try to use String.prototype.charCodeAt()

Comment: Instead of ignoring special characters, you should probably fix their encoding instead so that they compare as expected.

Comment: I really hope to avoid encoding hell, and make a comparison function that works in any case.

Comment: I assume that Ubuntu will have UTF-8 encoding. Between the line I read, that you developed with Windows, so this file might be in CP-1252. So maybe you ä is not properly encoded and thus fails on Ubuntu. See http://superuser.com/questions/239810/setting-utf8-as-default-character-encoding-in-windows-7

Comment: @VilleMiekk-oja: You can only avoid encoding hell by using the correct encoding, not by ignoring encodings.

Comment: But how can I use correct encoding in NodeJS? What is the encoding of env variable in ubuntu? I'm tempted to use the first answer provided here. I created a test: compared defined string (containing 'ä') to an env variable containing 'ä'. In localhost (windows) it works, but on the production server it fails. So it has to do something with env variable encoding mm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove any special character before comparison using RegExp:

You can choose to define the normal characters, or to define all special characters.

---

### Method - 1 Define the normal characters:

In this code, I keep only the alphabet.

```
function removeSpecial(s){
  return s.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/ig,'')
}

console.log(removeSpecial('abcd#@$ef')==removeSpecial('ab@@cdef')) // True

function compareSpecial(a,b){
   return removeSpecial(a)==removeSpecial(b)
}

console.log(compareSpecial('abcd#@$ef','ab@@cdef')) // True
```

---

### Method 2 - Define the special characters

You can remove only special chars (you can use regexp Unicode for that:

```
function removeSpecial(s){
  return s.replace(/[\u00E0-\u00F0]/ig,'')
}
```